# Azure AD B2C user group setup

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

So, Azure AD has me a bit confused and I'm wondering if I need Azure AD B2C or not for what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm setting up a asp.net core mvc entity framework webapp with the intention to sell subscriptions to users. These users can log in, add data and invite other users to join their group where they then can be assigned a role.

Am I right to think that I need to set up a B2C single tenant and use the Graph api to code groups and roles? Or can azure do this for me? Basically, what's best practices for setting up this kind of user/payment model?

Comment: Um.. for your scenario, I think AAD b2b is better for you.  Because these users need to invite other users to join their group.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT While this is true, I also need individuals with their own email account to sign up and then invite others to join. B2B is business accounts only right?

Comment: Actually, the most different for AAD B2B and B2C is that B2C can use other social IDP account to sign in your App. With AAD B2B all invited users will be created a work account in AAD. But they can use their emial address to sign in . So you need to do a choice.